# Unable to launch firefox 64 bit version 51.0.1 from notepad++ version 7.2.2

Tags: windows-7, firefox, 64-bit, notepad++

I used to be able to launch html files from notepad++ into the firefox browser.  I think when I upgraded to the Firefox 64 bit version was when this launch feature broke in NPP.

The path to this version of Firefox is C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"

My shortcuts.xml file that NPP uses to launch firefox is presented here:

```
<NotepadPlus>
<InternalCommands />
<Macros>
    <Macro name="Trim Trailing and save" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="83">
        <Action type="2" message="0" wParam="42024" lParam="0" sParam="" />
        <Action type="2" message="0" wParam="41006" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    </Macro>
</Macros>
<UserDefinedCommands>
    <Command name="Launch in Firefox" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="88">firefox &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
    <Command name="Launch in IE" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="73">iexplore &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
    <Command name="Launch in Chrome" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="82">chrome &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
    <Command name="Launch in Safari" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="70">safari &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
    <Command name="Get php help" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="112">http://www.php.net/$(CURRENT_WORD)</Command>
    <Command name="Google Search" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="113">https://www.google.com/search?q=$(CURRENT_WORD)</Command>
    <Command name="Wikipedia Search" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="114">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=$(CURRENT_WORD)</Command>
    <Command name="Open file" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="116">$(NPP_DIRECTORY)\notepad++.exe $(CURRENT_WORD)</Command>
    <Command name="Open in another instance" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="117">$(NPP_DIRECTORY)\notepad++.exe $(CURRENT_WORD) -nosession -multiInst</Command>
    <Command name="Send via Outlook" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="79">outlook /a &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
</UserDefinedCommands>
<PluginCommands />
<ScintillaKeys />
```

Appreciate your effort helping me resolve this.

Comment: Have you tried using the full path i.e `&quot;C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe&quot;  &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;`

Comment: I think you are close with this, but it still doesn't launch my html page. Firefox address bar shows this at launch:     file://///KBR-PC/Users/KBR/Udemy%20Web%20Dev%20Course/6.%20BOOTSTRAP/bootstrap3.3.7/djmarketing/multi-bg.html and this is my new shortcut.xml for firefox   <Command name="Launch in Firefox" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="88">&quot;C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe&quot; &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>

Comment: I suspect that the app paths key(s) (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx) are not working for you.  
Check:
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\firefox.exe
and
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\firefox.exe
to ensure you can launch Firefox.exe, without even needing it in the path.  You could even run ProcessMonitor to see this happening.

Comment: My registry settings for HKLM~\firefox look correct. 2 key value pairs. They are key=(default), value=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe and key=Path, value=C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox.  However, there wan't any entries under HKCU~/App Paths/firefox.exe.  So I tried created new entries that use same data as in HKLM, but this did not resolve the problem.

Comment: I have tried re-installing the 64bit version of firefox, but now I can't even load a html file by right clicking and selecting 'Open with' and selecting firefox in an attempt to load the file outside of Notepad++

Comment: Going to report this to Mozilla firefox.  I think my problems with notepad++ has something to do with this 64 bit version of firefox.  Within firefox menu, option to open a file isn't working either.  But, I can get this to work 1 time only when I choose Options->Help->Troubleshooting Information->Refresh Firefox.. After doing this procedure I either open a file through firefox or windows explorer to display in the firefox browser.  I can do this repeatedly until I close the browser and then after that things stop working again until the next Refresh Firefox.